# Мониторинг своего пк на веб

Tags: веб-программирование, железо

Понимаю, возможно мой вопрос не совсем корректный, но мне просто стало интересно, а в интернете инфы по этому поводу особо нет (может я плохо ищу).
Суть следующая, могу ли я каким-то образом получить доступ к ресурсам своего пк, а если быть точным, то к его производительности, аля "Диспетчер задач" для веб. Почему для веб? Потому что есть css, которым я могу придать любой вид своему мониторингу. 
Возможно есть уже готовые решения или что-то на подобии, то просьба не кидаться, а любезно подсказать.

P.S. Что-то там, как я понял, есть для PHP, но там берется статистика сервера и данные могут быть не совсем точные.

Comment: С сервера данные могут быть не точные? Как это ;-). Насчет вопроса: можете попробовать на PHP `system('tasklist');`

Comment: Не точные в плане того, что выделено может быть не вся память или не все ядра. Кстати на счет system я подумаю, хорошая идея.

Comment: `Zabbix` смотрел?

Comment: @donRumata Нет не видел, спасибо!